# Transmit JSON data to Django website

Tags: python, django, json

I'm transmitting a `application/json` in java with a `HttpPost` to a server which use Django.

I am performing the transmission as described here: [JSON POST request parsing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391302/json-post-request-parsing-in-php/8391451#8391451)

How can I create a page that receive this json data ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can receive json through `request.raw_post_data`

```
data=simplejson.loads( request.raw_post_data )
```

Comment: For django 1.4+, use request.body as request.raw_post_data is deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10990800/1011746

Answer (score 1):

the `request` variable in [your views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/) have a property `request.POST` which contains post data. this is (well technically, acts like) a dictionary. you also want to have a look at the [json module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) in python's standard library

in the end i guess you'll want something like

```
def my_view(request):
    # error checking omitted here, e.g. what if nothing is posted
    # or the json is invalid etc.
    posted_json = request.POST['my_json_variable']
    my_dict = json.loads(posted_json)

    # do something with the data
```

Comment: Stop me if I'm wrong, but that would work it I submit a form where one of the field is a json variable (with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). Here I transmit only a json object. The java request is done as explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391302/json-post-request-parsing-in-php/8391451#8391451

Comment: @MartinTrigaux: You are incorrect in so far as the request object will still contain your data. If you need more information how to access it, consider looking at the documentation, rather than complaining that second hasn't written the exact right code for you.

Comment: Sorry but no, I've tried the code, I catch a MultiValueDictKeyError when I try to get something in the `request.POST`. And by the way, where do you see that I'm complaining ? I just ask more info because it seemed to me it wasn't working, no reason to down vote the question for that...