# Missing json array in post request to php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to send json object from Android device to PHP to insert it to database, but server can't find it. What I did wrong? Thanks.

Script fails in isset check.

PHP Script:

```
    <?php

$json_array = json_decode($_POST['messages']) -> messages;

if(isset($json_array))
{
    //connect to database and do insertions.
} else
{
    echo "Not found array with messages in POST request\n";
}
```

Post request contains:

```
{"messages":[{"message":"Hello. Test from ukraine","id":1,"from_sender":"1111-111-1111","box":"2","type":"sms"}]}
```

And it's formed like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            try {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(BASE_URL + "/josyko.php");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("messages", request.toString()));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST, $json_array);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

```
$json_array = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) -> messages;
```

Or a better solution:

```
file_get_contents('php://input'); // instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
```

Comment: Do not use `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`. [PHP Manual says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data), “the preferred method for accessing the raw POST data is `php://input`”.

Comment: On my local machine and webhosting it's working with $_POST, but on other hosting it's not working...
I don't think that the problem is in $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391302/json-post-request-parsing-in-php
Answer found here.

Thanks guys for trying to help